# phpMailer connects then report a non connection

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

Ive got a most particular error

This is the result

```
2022-05-19 20:33:57 Connection: opening to mail.stms.africa:465, timeout=300, options=array()
2022-05-19 20:33:57 Connection: opened
2022-05-19 20:36:57 SMTP INBOUND: ""
2022-05-19 20:36:57 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2022-05-19 20:36:57 Connection: closing due to error
2022-05-19 20:36:57 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

and this is the code

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once "../composer/vendor/autoload.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

//Enable SMTP debugging.
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                               
//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();            
//Set SMTP host name                          
$mail->Host = "mail.xxx.xxx";
//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
//Provide username and password     
$mail->Username = "info@stms.africa";                 
$mail->Password = "xxxx";                           
//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                           
//Set TCP port to connect to
$mail->Port = 465;                                   

$mail->From = "info@stms.xxx";
$mail->FromName = "Me";

$mail->addAddress("anthony_langne@outlook.com", "Recepient Name");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

try {
    $mail->send();
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your issue:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 465;
```

That combination won't work. You can either do this:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
```

or

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
```

As in all the PHPMailer examples and [as described in the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#encryption-flavours).

Comment: Thank you. You are a genius. Ive been at it for two hours and you solved it in two seconds. Thanks

Comment: I checked the server hostname they forgot to remove from the logs. It is the latter one, the mode needs to be `ssl`, not `tls`. `ssl` establishes the encryption before the SMTP session, [as one would expect these days] `tls` uses the old `STARTTLS` directive to negotiate encryption within the SMTP session. The PHPmailer constants for these values are a bit more descriptive of their function: `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS` vs `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS`.